# How to validate my form when it is empty and submitted show an error in php?

Tags: php

I am new in php. My form is working properly but its show successful message even when it is empty and submitted.

How to show an error message when the form is submitted empty?

Here is the code :

```
if(empty($_POST['submit']) === false) {
    $email = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
    $logname = 'email.txt';
    $logcontents = file_get_contents($logname);
    if(strpos($logcontents,$email)) {
        die('You are already subscribed.');
    } else {
        $filecontents = $email.', ';
        $fileopen = fopen($logname,'a+');
        $filewrite = fwrite($fileopen,$filecontents);
        $fileclose = fclose($fileopen);
        if(!$fileopen or !$filewrite or !$fileclose or '') {
            die('Error occured');
        } else {
            echo 'Your email has been added.';
        }
    }   
} else {
    showForm();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Difficult to be helpful without seeing the HTML for the form.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is easy, you should have found it yourself ;-)
I added a check for empty eMail field, and then show an errorMessage and the form again.

```
if(empty($_POST['submit']) === false) {

    if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
        echo 'Please enter an email to add in the email field!';
        showForm();
    } else {

        $email = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['email']));

        $logname = 'email.txt';
        $logcontents = file_get_contents($logname);

        if(strpos($logcontents,$email)) {
            die('You are already subscribed.');
        } else {
            $filecontents = $email.', ';
            $fileopen = fopen($logname,'a+');
            $filewrite = fwrite($fileopen,$filecontents);
            $fileclose = fclose($fileopen);
            if(!$fileopen or !$filewrite or !$fileclose or '') {
                die('Error occured');
            } else {
                echo 'Your email has been added.';
            }
        }   
    }
} else {
    showForm();
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: I find it hard to add much comment, because it is such a trivial code. But thanks for telling me that i should improve my answer.